# Is there a SignaturePad that could be used in Ionic5/Angular9 PWA application?

Tags: angular, ionic5, signaturepad

I want to include a signaturepad on a PWA aplication built with Ionic5/Angular9. I'm looking for a component that could be used inside my application. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been researching for the same and found this: https://github.com/ramsatt/Angular9SignaturePad I have tried it on the latest ionic with Angular 9 on the browser however haven’t had the time yet to test it on an emulator or a device as such.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was what I'm looking for. I have tested it on my PWA built with Ionic 5 / Angular 9. It worked perfectly.